# SQL slowness under ADO Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ado.net

I need to create a `csv` file that will contain all current Subscribers, plus a series of strings that came from the database.

to fetch all Subscribers I'm doing:

```
public IQueryble<Subscribers> ListAllSubscribersByCalendarId(Decimal cid)
{
    return db.Subscribers.Where(x => x.calendar_id.Equals(cid));
}
```

pretty simple.

problem is that I already have more than **5000** and this **takes forever** (literally)!

even to show the last 30 records only, takes long long time, my query is:

```
public IQueryble<Subscribers> ListLast30SubscribersByCalendarId(Decimal cid)
{
    return db.Subscribers
               .Where(x => x.calendar_id.Equals(cid))
               .Take(30)
               .OrderByDescending(x => x.created_date);
}
```

What can I do to speed up this process?

Comment: 5000 records isn't a lot.  Do you have proper indexing?

Comment: Why is the "calendar_id" a Decimal and not an int or long? Is there something else about this query that is non-standard? Perhaps some more info would help.

Comment: @Mufasa, that's .NET way of translating the Sql data type `numeric` by default.

Comment: re: Decimal/numeric. I know. Why are you using a minimum 5-byte floating point number instead of the standard non-floating integers that are 4-byte? I mean, the size difference isn't too big a deal but the need to use floating point fields seems unnecessary if you are using them for clustering primary keys (assuming you are). I don't know much about the SQL engine internals, but that seems like an odd choice. So I was wondering if there are other unusual things going on with this particular database. What does the query analyzer report for these queries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should really happen in a stored procedure. Let the database server do what it's good at:like run queries crazy fast.

Comment: then, what's the point of using expressions like `Take`or `OrderBy` ?

Comment: For small sets, LINQ can ease the already-small complexity and performance hit of making a round trip to the SQL server. When you start dealing with thousands of records, though, remember that the server is there for a reason, and not just to act as a persistent data store. SQL is powerful:let your investment in your db work for you.

Comment: @balexandre You are asking the wrong question (1st comment) The question that should be asked is should I use LINQ(EF) for this.

Comment: @David much better explanation, "it's easier to code" is not a comment! I will make use of SP in this case, thank you for the heads up.

Comment: Stored procedures aren't the answer for everything. In this case, any tool/framework/library that can auto-generate the SQL code based on those LINQ operators will perform nearly the same as the stored procedure, assuming the database is normalized, marked with foreign keys, and indexed properly. Examples: NHibernate, Entity Framework, etc.

Comment: @Mufasa That's a huge assumption - it depends entirely on the framework and the skills of the SQL developer. Modern compilers generate very tight code, but they'll never be able to *beat* a very experienced assembly programmer in terms of raw efficiency. Also, normalization (while a necessity in any good DB design) actually HURTS performance since it scatters data amongst different pages.

Answer (score 3):

Your expression is one that needs be checked on the client and cannot be converted to a SQL statement. So if you run **SQL profiler**, I bet you will see records trickling one by one to the client.

Change the condition to `x.calendar_id == cid`

Comment: but, instead `==` the same as `Object.Equals(...)` ?

Comment: I know, but give it a try, if did not work let me know to delete the response. Linq is a lot of magic behind the scene and I am not sure what it translate to.

Comment: I measured the time. Using  `.Equals` is faster than `==` 145ms against 172ms

Answer (score 1):

Aliostad's answer should help a lot. Also ensure that the `calendar_id` field is indexed correctly.

First, I'm just checking that you want to take the first 30 however the database determines which the first 30 are, and *then* sort those 30 by created date? If you want to grab the first 30 based on their creation date, then you'll want to include the `created_date` in your index appropriately so it can be used in the query.

Finally, this answer assumes you are using a tool that correctly maps these LINQ operators to an appropriate SQL query, and isn't just doing this entire operation on the entire record set in memory.

Comment: with 5000 records index will not help.

Comment: I added some clarity to my answer to show that 5000 records shouldn't be a problem if indexed correctly with the right LINQ to SQL/ORM tool.

Answer (score 1):

two possible options:

create a nonclustered index for x.calendar_id:

or do the ordering in the application instead of sql:

```
public IQueryble<Subscribers> ListLast30SubscribersByCalendarId(Decimal cid)
{
    return db.Subscribers
               .Where(x => x.calendar_id.Equals(cid))
               .Take(30)
}

var ordered =  ListLast30SubscribersByCalendarId(1).ToList().OrderByDescending(x => x.created_date);
```